# Display message from Servlet to JSF page

Tags: servlets, jsf-2, facelets

I'm trying to display success message in xhtml page from servlet but no luck, here's my code
In servlet i have

```
FacesContextFactory contextFactory = (FacesContextFactory)FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.FACES_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
            LifecycleFactory lifecycleFactory = (LifecycleFactory)FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.LIFECYCLE_FACTORY); 
            Lifecycle lifecycle = lifecycleFactory.getLifecycle(LifecycleFactory.DEFAULT_LIFECYCLE); 
            FacesContext facesContext = contextFactory.getFacesContext(request.getSession().getServletContext(), request, response, lifecycle); 
            facesContext.addMessage( "user:displaymessagesave", new FacesMessage("user saved successfully" ));
```

In xhtml page inside form i have written tag for display  message form id=user

```
<h:message class="success" for="displaymessagesave" id="displaymessagesave" />
```

Saving to database is happening but its not displaying any message, please suggest where i'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to access FacesContext from a servlet other than `FacesServlet`.

Recently I faced that same problem, and what I did was, on my servlet, put the messages in the Session:

```
 List<String> msgs=(List<String>)request.getSession().getAttribute(KEY);
 if (msgs==null)
 {
   msgs=new ArrayList<String>();
 }
 msgs.add("My new message");
 request.getSession().setAttribute(KEY, msgs);
```

Then, on the xhtml view, I added a call to put these messages on FacesContext, and a `growl` element:

```
<h:outputText value="#{managed.prepareMessages()}"/>
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="false" life="4000" />
```

Finally, the `prepareMessages` method takes them from session and add the messages to `FacesContext`:

```
public String prepareMessages()
{
    List<String> msgs = (List<String>)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                            .getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get(KEY);
    if (msgs!=null)
    {
        for(String msg:msgs)
        {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                                                     new FacesMessage(msg));
        }
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                                      .getSessionMap().remove(KEY);
    }
    return "";
}
```

It may not be an elegant solution, but is the only one I found...

Answer (score 0):

Don't give the same id for message as the "for" component. If you just want a messageholder without attaching it to a valueholder than you should use the  tag.

```
<h:messages class="success" id="displaymessagesave" />
```

Comment: i tried using only id but still the same its not displaying any message.

Comment: Have your tried it with h:messages instead of h:message?

Comment: You also have to update the h:messages component to see the message on the UI.